# How do I run startup scripts for DOCKER when deployed via Cloud Compute Engine instances?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I'm creating an instance template under GCP's Cloud Engine section.

Usually when deploying a docker image, there's a docker file that includes some startup scripts after specifying the base image to pull and build, but I can't see where I can either submit a docker file, or enter startup scripts.

I can see a field for startup scripts for the Cloud Compute instance, but that's different from the scripts passed on for the Docker's startup.

Are these perhaps to be filled in under "Command", "Command arguments", or "Environment Variables"?

[image: Screenshot of the GUI I'm seeing]

For clarification, this is someone else's image of a dockerfile I pulled from Google Images. The part I wish to add is "rectangled" in red, the RUN commands, but not these exact commands.

In my case, I would like to add something like

`RUN python /pythonscript.py`

[image: RUN commands]

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well, you are trying to create a Docker image not a compute instance image.

Compute instance can run a docker image that you already builded and pushed to either gcr or any other repository.

Try to build your docker image normaly, push it in a docker repo then use it.

Comment: no, the docker image has already been made and pushed. This compute engine will deploy it from the repo, and I want to run some startup commands. I have added an example in OP to clarify.

Comment: Man... That's what we saif me and Ivan... you need to build an image... The RUN command is used only during container image build...

Answer (score 0):

You can run a startup script directly in the Docker container by using a ‘command’ section. If you need to install something after starting a container for example Apache, you should use a Docker image that has [Apache](https://hub.docker.com/_/httpd).

If you need to run some other arguments, like creating environment variables, [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/compute/instances/create-with-container) you can find the full list of flags when creating a container image on VM instance.

Comment: doesn't seem to be exactly environment variables either, I have added an example in OP to clarify.

Comment: As you want to have installs in the startup script, it is better to create a [dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/) and create a new docker image. Basically you take a base image and install extra applications on top of it. When you have your docker image created you can push it to Google Cloud Registry.

Startup script is not a guarantee that you will have everything installed as the VM will need some time to start and get access to internet. You should use startup script to start an application or similar, but not to continue creating the Docker image.

Comment: Yes, I want startup scripts to start some pre-written .py scripts saved in / and are already committed into the docker image, not to continue building the image. How do I add a startup script in that GUI?

Comment: I have been searching in different places, I think you should use bash script and specify py file from there. If you check [this link](https://serverfault.com/questions/594281/how-can-i-override-cmd-when-running-a-docker-image) you will see that endpoints in docker can be replaced with bash scripts.

Here is the example of the script. 
```#!/bin/bash 
echo "import time 
print(time.time())" > test.py 
python test.py 
python /path/to/file.py```

Save your script in docker image and put its path in the Command part when creating VM instance. 
I hope this helps.